# Selected ng-options item doesn't stick to 'combo box'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and am struggling with something that should be easy.

I have this ugly looking page:
[image]

Users add new beers on this screen and a beer may have more than one style - so the 'Add' button creates a new 'Style' combo box and the 'Remove' on the left side, well, removes it.

Problem is when the user selects one style from the list it doesn't appear as selected in the combo box - ie, the style field will be empty after the dropdown list has been collapsed/closed again.

So here is my code:

**Beer View**

```
   <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="style in beer.styles">
        <label for="style" class="col-sm-1 control-label" ng-if="$index == 0" >Style</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1" ng-if="$index > 0">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeStyle($index)">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-control"
                  ng-controller="styleCtrl"
                  ng-model="selectedStyleId"
                  ng-options="style.id as style.name for style in styles"
                  ng-change="updateStyle($index, selectedStyleId)">
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addNewStyle()">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Style Controller (Dummy Impl)**

```
.controller('styleCtrl', ["$scope", "$location", function ($scope, $location) {
  $scope.styles = [
    { 'id': '1',
      'name': 'Lager' },
    { 'id': '2',
      'name': 'American Blonde Ale' },
    { 'id': '3',
      'name': 'American Stout' },
    { 'id': '4',
      'name': 'Cream Ale' },
    { 'id': '5',
      'name': 'Bock' },
    { 'id': '6',
      'name': 'German Pilsener' }
  ];
}]);
```

**Beer Controller**

```
.controller('beerCtrl', ["$scope", "$location", function ($scope, $location) {
  $scope.beer = {
    'styles': [
        { 'id' : '-1' }
    ]
  }

  $scope.addNewStyle = function() {
    $scope.beer.styles.push({ 'id': '-1' });
  }

  $scope.removeStyle = function(index) {
    $scope.beer.styles.splice(index, 1);
  }

  $scope.updateStyle = function(index, styleId) {
    $scope.beer.styles[index] = { 'id': styleId };
  }
```

The styleId is correctly set in the array, the only problem really is in the screen.

Have you spotted anything wrong in my code?

P.S.: I suspect the fact I have two controllers - the BeerController and a 'nested' StyleController in the same view may be related to the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned I'm brand new to AngularJS so my mistake was rather simple. Instead of using on-change, I've binded the selected value to the backing object directly:

```
 <select class="form-control"
          ng-controller="styleCtrl"
          ng-model="beer.styles[$index].id"
          ng-options="style.id as style.name for style in styles">
```

That got the job done. Silly oversight.